# How should I get the add assign trait to work for a vector within a struct?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

New to rust. Would like to understand why this issue is occuring and how to fix. I don't think I can change the signature for the implementation of the trait method either which makes this more harder to fix.

```
use std::ops::{AddAssign};

pub struct ColumnVector {
    pub data: Vec<f32>
}

impl AddAssign for &ColumnVector {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self) {
        for (index, elem) in other.data.iter().enumerate() {
            self.data[index] += elem;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    
}
```

Comment: [Just remove the `&`?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b61135f49807088d9e44fa84efc8e42) is there something I'm missing here? You can't change a shared reference to a mutable one.

Comment: Why are you implementing it on `&ColumnVector` instead of just `ColumnVector`?

Comment: @JaredSmith the location where this operator is used does not own the column vector. Actually I'm wondering if I impliment it for the ColumnVector straight up does it allow it to work on & and &mut?

Comment: @BrianYeh "the location where this operator is used does not own the column vector" not usually relevant. "if I impliment it for the ColumnVector straight up does it allow it to work on & and &mut?" Yes, usually those will be automatically dereferenced for you, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules

Answer (score 1):

Using the `&` creates an immutable reference to `ColumnVector` and its fields, so you cannot get a mutable reference to update it.

You could do:

```
pub struct ColumnVector {
    pub data: Vec<f32>
}


impl AddAssign for &mut ColumnVector {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self) {
        for (index, elem) in other.data.iter().enumerate() {
            self.data[index] += elem;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    
}
```

if you needed the borrow, but you probably just want to remove the `&` entirely.

For context:

You can *either* have n-number of immutable borrows, or a single mutable one. There are ways around this (read about interior mutability) but generally you must have exclusive access to a variable to change it.

When you borrowed `ColumnVector`, you could not later edit the field because you did not own the data.